# CSS LAYOUT POSITIONING positioning my header logo

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a website but I am having a problem positioning my header logo. When i am trying to position the img, it will position to the way that i wanted but when i minimize the browser it is extending the layout and the position is changing. Please help. I dont know what is going on.

Here are the codes on css

```
#main_header{
    /*background-image:url('./images/bgheader4.jpg');*/
    background-color: white;
    background-size: 100% 100% ;
    height: 660px;
    width: 100%; 
    position: relative;
}

 #main_header img {
    margin-left: 15%;

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: go to http://jsfiddle.net and make an example of whats happenening. replicate your code

Answer (score 0):

take away the `#main_header` behind the `#main_header img` and give it the image a  class instead. Otherwise it will inherit all the attributes of main_header which may not be what you want. Take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0n1bp14c/) and see how it works (I have just used a random image).

Answer (score 0):

My wild guess is that you are using the `<img>` inside of a parent `<div>` which is making it inherit its attributes. 
You could do it that way:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#main-header
{
height: 150px;
background-color: white;
text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id = "main-header">
<img src = "stacoverflowlogo.jpg" alt = "stackoverflowlog" height = '100' width = '100'/>
<header>
Welcome to StackOverflow!
</header>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Or you should take out the `<img>` from its parent element and give it a separate `id`, something like:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#main-header
{
height: 150px;
background-color: white;
text-align: center;
}
#image
{ 
margin-left: 45%;
position: relative;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<img  id = "image" src = "stacoverflowlogo.jpg" alt = "stackoverflowlog" height = '100' width = '100'/>
<div id = "main-header">
<header>
Welcome to StackOverflow!
</header>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```